# Problem to define a macro with xparse

Tags: tikz-pgf, xparse

With

`\def\drawcircle#1
     {\node [draw] at (\getFromList{#1}{1}) [circle through={(\getFromList{#1}{2})}] {};}`

I get what I want but with

`\NewDocumentCommand{\drawcircle}{m}
 {
 node [draw] at (\getFromList{#1}{1}) [circle through={(\getFromList{#1}{2})}] {};
 }`

Something's wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newList}{m}
 {\seq_new:c { l_am_list_#1_seq }}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addToList}{mm}
 {\seq_put_right:cn { l_am_list_#1_seq } { #2 }}
\NewDocumentCommand{\getFromList}{mm}
 {\seq_item:cn { l_am_list_#1_seq } { #2 }}
 \NewDocumentCommand{\drawcircle}{m}
 {
 node [draw] at (\getFromList{#1}{1}) [circle through={(\getFromList{#1}{2})}] {};
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% \def\drawcircle#1
% {\node [draw] at (\getFromList{#1}{1}) [circle through={(\getFromList{#1}{2})}] {};}

\begin{document}

\newList{C_1}
\addToList{C_1}{A}
\addToList{C_1}{B}
\newList{C_2}
\addToList{C_2}{B}
\addToList{C_2}{C}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (C) at (0,-3);
  \drawcircle{C_1}
  \drawcircle{C_2}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in `\ExplSyntaxOn` and that's why you should write `circle~through` instead of `circle through`.

Comment: Sorry just fine !

Comment: Where is in the documentation ?

Comment: In `ExplSyntax`, the spaces are not significant. However, the space in the Tikz option `circle through` must be a *real* space (otherwise, it will become the option `circlethrough` which does not exist). That's why we have to put a significant space (`~` in `ExplSyntax`). There are often such `~` to put in Tikz instructions in `ExplSyntax`.

Comment: In fact, if your definition by `\def` was in `ExplSyntax`, we would have to put the `~` and if you have used your `\NewDocumentCommand` outside `ExplSyntax`, it would have worked without the `~`. In fact, the problem has nothing to oo with `\NewDocumentCommand` and `\def`. It's only a problem at the intersection of Tikz and `ExplSyntax`.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments ! very useful !! I start with l3